# How to put an author in swagger editor?

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-editor

I recently documented my API and I need to specify the author to make it available. If anyone can help me I would be very grateful. I use OpenAPI (swagger editor) 3.0

I tried looking in the official documentation, GitHub and even here but I didn't find anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can specify the author in your OpenAPI 3.0 documentation:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Your API Title
  description: Your API Description
  version: 1.0.0
  contact:
    name: Your Name
    email: your.email@example.com
```